# Is it possible to compile Angular 5 TypeScript on save, when Visual Studio is running with/without debugging?

Tags: angular, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, angular5

So we run a pretty huge ASP.NET MVC project here. On one view, I need to include a `@Partial()` to my Angular 5 project. This Angular project was simply initialised using `ng new PROJECTNAME`.

Right now I have to `cd` into the project folder and run `ng build` to make it build manually. I've added a MSBuild to my csproj file, so it automatically runs the `ng build` command, when I run the project (with debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>), without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), or simply build (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)).

This is extremely annoying, as it takes a pretty long time to compile (about 10 seconds), which I have to do every time I make a change.

If I simply run the project using `ng serve`, it auto-compiles on save in like 1 second.

Is it possible to mimic this behavior, so my code compiles faster than `ng build` does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more you know:

`ng build --watch`

That's literally all. It will listen for file changes and compile only the affected files (I guess).

EDIT: Don't put this into the MSBuild configuration, because that will mess it up. Even if you add it in `BeforeBuild` or `AfterBuild`, it won't start the web server and so on.

My solution:

1. Build the project and run it (with/without debugging)
2. Open CMD and `cd` into the folder
3. Run the `ng build --watch` command and have it in a seperate window

That was the only solution I could find working, so it didn't add time to compile the application, which is not something you want to do in a big solution with many projects, as the chance of you working on that specific page is kind of low.

Comment: Is there any better-integrated solution to this in Visual Studio?